# Network connection b/w two pc for turtlebot?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

Can I use the ad-hoc network to connect between the turtlebot laptop and workstation laptop both having wifi capability. Since I want to map a large area, I dont want to connect to a static wifi router, rather have flexibility to carry the workstation laptop to further distance where turtlebot goes.
Will I be able to ssh between two laptops by ad-hoc network connection?
Or can you suggest any alternative. In short I dont want to use the router for flexibility.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44808/network-connection-b/w-two-pc-for-turtlebot?/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can very well use the ad-hoc connection between the workstation and the TurtleBot laptop. You will be able to ssh too, No problem! I have used the ad-hoc connection and it worked well.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2012-10-11**:
for some reason i am unable to create an ad-hoc network on ubuntu 11.10/macbook on workstation pc. Any suggestions why am I not able to and how to solve this.